# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, graphics-card

When I run `nvidia-smi` it fails and throws an error:

> "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
>   driver"

And When I run `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`, it gives the below output. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

```
390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     i386         NVIDIA libcompute package


ii  libnvidia-compute-418:amd64                     418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package


ii  libnvidia-container-tools                       1.0.2-1                                      amd64        NVIDIA container runtime library (command-line tools)

ii  libnvidia-container1:amd64                    1.0.2-1                                      amd64        NVIDIA container runtime library


ii  libnvidia-decode-418:amd64                      418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries


ii  libnvidia-encode-418:amd64                      418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library


ii  libnvidia-fbc1-418:amd64                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library


ii  libnvidia-gl-418:amd64                          418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD


ii  libnvidia-ifr1-418:amd64                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library


ii  nvidia-compute-utils-418                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities


iU  nvidia-container-runtime                        2.0.0+docker18.09.6-3                        amd64        NVIDIA container runtime


iU  nvidia-container-runtime-hook                   1.4.0-1                                      amd64        NVIDIA container runtime hook


ii  nvidia-dkms-418                                 418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package


ii  nvidia-driver-418                               418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage


ii  nvidia-kernel-common-418                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module


ii  nvidia-kernel-source-418                        418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package


ii  nvidia-modprobe                                 418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files


ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.8.2                                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime


ii  nvidia-settings                                 418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver


ii  nvidia-utils-418                                418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries


ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418                   418.67-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver## Heading ##
```

Comment: Adding what's the error you're getting with `nvidia-smi` would be useful too.

Comment: I have added the error.

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot at UEFI.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve your problem? I have a very similar problem with yours with the same driver version (418.67)